# Example of set with irrational upper arithmetic density?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

All the examples i can think of have rational density.

Comment: Are you familiar with the (infinite) [_Fibonacci Word_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word)?

Comment: Generically, the set of numbers of the form $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$ for $\alpha\gt 1$ will have density $\frac1\alpha$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence for more details on this.

Answer (score 5):

The square-free integers have natural density $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Do you know if the densities of cube free integers, etc. have similarly interesting values?

Comment: Same argument. The cube-free integers have natural density $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}$, where $\zeta(3)$ is the sum of the reciprocals of the cubes.  It turns out that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational.

Comment: Ah, I think I see where it comes from now. Could you go into more detail about the argument, though?

Comment: A proof is sketched [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer)